# How to sort arrays in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting

I need to write sorting code array function in bash and first input is number of number
and end return array sorted for example :: input 5 2 4 10 1 4returns 1 2 4 4 10

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sort+bash+array

Comment: Can the input be given in a file, or should it be in a bash variable?

Answer (score 2):

The following script sorts array `a` where first element in the array is the number of elements in the array. The result is stored in variable `b`

```
#! /bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' a=( 3 3 2 1 )
b=$(sort <<< "${a[*]:1}")
echo ${b[*]}
```